# Hibernate envers - getting revision timestamp and audited entity in same query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I starting using hibernate envers (5.3.28) and it works fine. 5.3.28 due to my JEE environment.
Entities are annotated, tables created (using ddl2 "create" for development), audit records will be written.

Using AuditReaderFactory to play with audit data in "vertical" and "horizontal" layers.

My problem is on vertical layer.

I get the audited entities for a specific id (works fine).

E.g: I use

```
List<Service> services = AuditReaderFactory.get(em).createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Service.class, true, true)
    .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(serviveId)).getResultList();
```

I also want to get the revison timestamp in same query (additinally, here I stuck).

I tried to use `.addProjection`. So I can get the revison timestamp (many examples in the internet). It works.
But I also want the whole entity as object.

Similar to  `"SELECT r.timestamp, s FROM Service s ....."`.
So "s" is the entity PLUS the timestamp.

`AuditEntity.selectEntity(false)` is not the same, it is just the hash structure of my entity.

Any hint?

Uwe/Germany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself, had a look to the envers source code/docu.

Just using a 'AuditQuery' without any projection.

```
AuditQuery q = AuditReaderFactory.get(em).createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Service.class, false, true);
List<?> results = q.getResultList();
for ( Object row : results) {
   Object[] array = (Object[]) row;
   System.out.println("  array: " + array.length);
   System.out.println("    0: " + array[0].getClass() + " = " + array[0]);
   System.out.println("    1: " + array[1].getClass() + " = " + array[1]);
   System.out.println("    2: " + array[2].getClass() + " = " + array[2]);
}
```

You will get object array with three entries.

```
0: class mypackage.Service = <my data> from toString
1: class org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity$HibernateProxy$rRq8ZPJf = DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 2, revisionDate = 12.05.2023, 10:12:17)
2: class org.hibernate.envers.RevisionType = ADD
```